# set latitude and longitude string format javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change code below to use "onsubmit" instead of "onblur" where javascript will validate if my latitude/longitude format are correct.
The format of lat/long is (numbers.numbers, numbers.numbers) 
where numbers=any length and between 0-9. All help are appreciated.

HTML

```
Latitude, Longitude <input type="text" id="formatGPS" onblur="checkGPS(this);" /><button>Enter</button>
```

Javascript

```
function checkGPS(inputGPS) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9].[0-9], [0-9].[0-9]$", "i");
    var formatGPS = inputGPS.value;
    if ((formatGPS.length > 0) && !regex.test(formatGPS)) {
        alert("The format is always as follows: numbers.numbers, numbers.numbers (With numbers=any length)");

    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qc2bd/104/

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+, [0-9]+\.[0-9]+$", "i");
```

Although this will force a number to be always there, so zero would be 0.0. Also 000.000 would be valid. If this is what you want, this will work :).

Another thing is whether you need or not negative values, as sideroxylon pointed out, in that case the regexp would be:

```
^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+, -?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$
```

Comment: Don't you need to allow for negative values:  `^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+, -?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$`

Comment: Yeah negatives, you're right! Thanks, I'll update my answer and let OP decide how he likes it better